# Perfect conversion from <div> to <br> in a WYSIWYG editor

Tags: javascript, html, regex, rich-text-editor, sanitize

I need to sanitize HTML in a WYSIWYG editor. The output must not contain any `<div>`s. All `<div>` elements must be replaced with `<br>` elements. This original text MUST render the same as the sanitized text.

This is my attempt so far (notice the unwanted extra whitespace in the output)  – thanks to Nimit for the rendering containers:

```js
let text = `<div>aoeu</div><div><ul><li>eu</li><li>a</li></ul><div><br></div></div><div>eu</div>`;
// let text = 'aoeu<ul><li>aoeu</li><ul><li>aoue</li></ul></ul><div><br></div></div></div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div>oe</div><div><ul><li>u</li></ul></div>'

document.getElementById("pre1").innerHTML = "<strong>With Div</strong> </br>" + text;

text = text
.replace(/<div><div>(.*)<\/div><\/div>/g, '<div>$1</div>') // meaningless directly double wrapped divs
.replace(/<div><br><\/div>/g, '<br>') // div with a br is only one newline
.replace(/<div>(?!<div>)(.*?)<\/div>/g, '$1<br>') // divs always make a newline after

document.getElementById("pre2").innerHTML = "<strong>Without Div</strong> </br>" + text;
```

```css
.preContainer {
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.preContainer:first-child{
  border-right:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="preContainer"><pre id="pre1"></pre></div>

<div class="preContainer"><pre id="pre2"></pre></div>
```

So basically I can't seem to figure out how to perfectly convert from `<div>` to `<br>`. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Use `DOMParser` to parse your HTML, then manipulate the resulting DOM tree.  Using regex is going to give you a bad time.

Comment: I am familiar with `DOMParser`, but either way, `<div>` elements don't always have newlines after them, that's the main problem. For instance, in my example, `<div><div><br></div></div>` may only count as a single newline.

Comment: Is it only <div> you want to get rid of?... What can stay in the source and what must be removed?

Comment: Replacing `<div>`'s with `<br>`'s is the only thing I could not figure out. There are other requirements, but I've solved them, so no need to worry about anything else for this question.

Comment: Just eliminate all `<div>`, convert all `</div>` to `<br>` and then squash multiple consecutive `<br>` into one.

Comment: @Corion multiple `<br>`'s ARE allowed in the output, this solution will not work for many reasons. Stacked divs like this `<div><div><br></div></div>` would become 3 `<br>`s when they only render as one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve your result with below replace script.

```
.replace("<div>", "<br>").replace("</div>", "");
```

Check below snippet, you can inspect both `pre`, second `pre` doesn't have any `div` tag:

```js
function showItInPre(text){
  //let text = `aoeua<div><ul><li>oe</li><li>a</li><li>oeu</li></ul><div><br></div></div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div>aoe</div><div><ul><li>u</li></ul><div><br></div></div><div><br></div><div>u</div><div><div><br></div></div><div>o</div><div><ul><li>o</li><li>o</li><li>a</li><li><br></li></ul></div>`;

  document.getElementById("pre1").innerHTML = "<strong>With Div</strong> </br>" + text;

  text = text
  .replace(/<div><br><\/div>/ig, '<br>')
  .replace(/<\/div><\/div>/ig, '<br>')
  .replace(/<div>/ig, "").replace(/<\/div>/ig, "<br>");

  document.getElementById("pre2").innerHTML = "<strong>Without Div</strong> </br>" + text;
}


document.getElementById("testit").addEventListener("click", function(){showItInPre(document.getElementById("textarea").value)});
```

```css
.preContainer {
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  vertical-align:top;
}

#pre1{
  border-right:1px solid black;
}

#textarea {
width:500px; height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div><textarea id="textarea"></textarea><button id="testit">Test</button></div>

<div class="preContainer"><pre id="pre1"></pre></div>

<div class="preContainer"><pre id="pre2"></pre></div>
```

Comment: Nice snippet, it's easier to visualize that way. However, here's an example the regex fails on:

`oau<div><div><br></div></div><div>aoeu</div><div><div><br></div></div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div>aoeu</div><div><ul><li>aoe</li><li>u</li></ul></div>`

Comment: And another:

`aoeua<div><ul><li>oe</li><li>a</li><li>oeu</li></ul><div><br></div></div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div>aoe</div><div><ul><li>u</li></ul><div><br></div></div><div><br></div><div>u</div><div><div><br></div></div><div>o</div><div><ul><li>o</li><li>o</li><li>a</li><li><br></li></ul></div>`

Comment: Another counter example: `aoeu<br><div><br></div><div>aoeu</div><div><div><ul><li>aoeu</li><ul><li>aoue</li></ul></ul><div><br></div></div></div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div>oe</div><div><ul><li>u</li></ul></div>`

Comment: Yea working for few but not working for few more.. not a best solution. :)